# Online Walking List

Tags: evaluating-civicrm, civicrm-home

I am running a campaign for political office and the one thing we want to avoid is entering data after canvassing a neighborhood. What we want is to be able to have the same data that would be on a printed walking list available on the phone or a tablet. The volunteer should be able to update their entire interaction with the voter right from their phone or tablet and have it update the CiviCRM database.

Has anyone ever done this? How difficult would it be to customize something like this? Is there a plugin/add on available anywhere that already does this?

Answer (score 2):

You can definitively do this; my favourite solution for this (on Drupal) is Webform CiviCRM; It will let your canvassers run through forms collecting data on the go; You can even sell Memberships or add people to an Event - or a Group; or a Relationship; a Donation; etc all on the go! And all into your CiviCRM live;

Comment: Agree with this. You will probably also need a Drupal View so that you can see the list of names and some info about them as you walk down the street, and then click through via a link to preload the webform. That said, this all assumes you are using data/wifi with your tablet. If you mean 'offline' then pls clarify in the question.